# PostgreSQL doesn't update/copy boolean from subselect?

Tags: postgresql

Here's a short code sample that behaves unexpectedly for me in PostgreSQL v9.5:

```
create table test (a boolean, b boolean);
insert into test (a) values ('true'),('true'),('true'),('true'),('true');
update test set b = rand.val from (select random() > 0.5 as val from test) as rand;
```

I expect column b to take on random true/false values, but for some reason it's always false. If I run the subselect of:

```
select random() > 0.5 as val from test;
```

It returns random true/false combinations as I want. But for some reason once I try to update the actual table it fails. I've tried several casting combinations but it doesn't seem to help.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
update test set b = (random() > 0.5);
```

Comment: Well... that does work fantastically well :). Any idea why my attempt doesn't, though?

Comment: I'm a bit suspicious that your update syntax there isn't valid, but if it is then I think it's just taking the first value returned by the subquery and applying that to every row

Comment: Interesting -- I didn't think of that option but I think you're right. If I keep re-running the update the value in column b swaps between true and false.

Comment: Upon further reading, I think it's because I don't have a `where` clause that the multi-update doesn't work. Since it has nothing to match the first table to the subquery table, I guess it just takes the first value every time like you guessed. Very unexpected! I assumed that since the two tables had the same number of rows it'd just match them up. Oops.

Comment: Yes you'd definitely need a where clause to get the correct row, but of course here you don't need that.